# Facebook login causes you to be taken to "Help Center" if we try to login multiple times

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, facebook-login

Mine is a Xamarin based app which has multiple login options; of which FB Login is one of the options. Clicking "cancel" on the "confirm login" page on facebook login causes you to be taken to a troubleshooting page the next time you attempt.

Steps:
Open the app that is not currently logged in but has been logged in using facebook in the past.

1 - Click on Login (Existing User)

2 - Click Login with Facebook

3 - You should be taken to a "confirm login" page where is tells you "you previously logged in to App with Facebook"

4 - Click cancel and it takes you to the Login screen

5 - Press "Login with Facebook" again

6 - If done consecutively you will be taken to the Facebook help center

Please let me know if this is an expected behaviour or this needs to be handled.

The error I am getting when clicking cancel is:

```
error_reason=user_denied
 &error=access_denied
 &error_description=Permissions+error.
```

Comment: A quick search of the Facebook login docs shows this is [expected](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#nonjscancel)

Comment: Error message seems to be expected, but the behaviour; that is redirecting to Help Center is causing confusion..